# Android : Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclick, bitmapfactory

I have a SQLite database with two tables: Topic table and Vocab table. I want to display the vocab images when i click on the pictureButton, but the app crashes.

Choice.java

```
    public class Choice extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choice);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pictureButton: {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Choice.this, Pictureandtext.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.textButton: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get my intent from

```
    this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Smode.this, Choice.class);
            intent.putExtra("SelectedTopicId", id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is my `getImage()` method from the *DatabaseAccess.java*

```
    public byte[] getImage(int i) {
    //byte[] data = null;
    String selectImage = "SELECT VocabImage FROM Vocab WHERE VocabTopic =" + i;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectImage, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            cursor.getBlob(0);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return null;
}
```

Pictureandtext.java

```
    public class Pictureandtext extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);


protected Cursor cursor;
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView textView;
private int topicId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pictureandtext);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    topicId = getIntent().getIntExtra("SelectedTopicId", 0);

    databaseAccess.open();

    byte[] data = databaseAccess.getImage(topicId);
    Bitmap image = toBitmap(data);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

    /*String name = databaseAccess.getVocabName(topicId);
    textView.setText(name);*/
    databaseAccess.close();
}

public static Bitmap toBitmap(byte[] image){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

}

**EDITED!!**
I edited some coding and im still getting some error. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.user.displayvocab, PID: 29339
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.displayvocab/com.example.user.displayvocab.Pictureandtext}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                                   at com.example.user.displayvocab.Pictureandtext.toBitmap(Pictureandtext.java:47)
                                                                                   at com.example.user.displayvocab.Pictureandtext.onCreate(Pictureandtext.java:38)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Comment: Add this code in getImage() method -> if (cursur == null) return null;

Comment: Can you show me how should i add it? Thanks

Comment: Add after rawQuery

Comment: I have added it (see updated coding) but the app still crash and it says "attempt to get length of null array". Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: see the coding remove last return null and add your output

Answer (score 1):

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.user.displayvocab, PID:
>   24087 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick at

**Problem**

```
   case R.id.pictureButton: {
    setContentView(R.layout.pictureandtext); // Remove this line

............

 case R.id.textButton: {
            setContentView(R.layout.menu); // Remove this line
            break;
        }
```

> setContentView->Set the activity content to an explicit view. This
>   view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy.

Why you calling **[setContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))** multiple-time ? Remove this line .You can show **[DIALOG](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)** there .

Comment: I removed them and created a new class so when I onclick pictureButton it should bring to the new class. But the app still crashes and no error is shown this time. Could it be something wrong with my getImage method?